# I'm trying to use cross_val_score on my Random Forest Regression but the scores are weird

Tags: python, regression, random-forest, cross-validation

I am using Random Forest for my Regression problem in python. I have rather large data (5 features, 1 target, with 9387 dataset).

At first, to obtain the accuracy, I used a simple RF code with `train_test_split` and `metrics.r2_score` and the result gave me a 0.9999 score on both train set and test set. Later, I tried to perform cross-validation using `cross_val_score` with 5 Folds. This gives me 5 numbers *(see below)* which I found some of them are weird to be the score of cross-validation.

[-1.44202691  0.25338018  0.70433516  0.98278159 -3.34943088]

Is it really possible to have a negative accuracy or there is something just wrong with how I code?
I am still new to coding and python so please bear with me. You can see my code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import csv
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split
from statistics import mean

data = pd.read_csv("Size1.csv", sep=",")

data = data[["X", "Y", "Z", "Tilt_C", "Tilt_A", "Radiation_C"]]
predict = "Radiation_C"

A = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
B = np.array(data[predict])

# Split data for Train and Test
a_train, a_test, b_train, b_test = train_test_split(A, B, test_size=0.25)


# Fitting Random Forest Regression to the dataset

# create regressor object
rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)

# fit the regressor with A and B data
rf.fit(a_train, b_train)


# Calculate accuracy
b_pred = rf.predict(a_test)
print('R^2:', metrics.r2_score(b_test, b_pred))


# Perform Cross Validation & scores
scores = cross_val_score(rf,A, B, cv=5)
print(scores)
print("Mean: ", mean(scores))
```